# Error no primary key in a table with two foreign key

Tags: sql

I have two tables `Maquinista` and `Tractorista`.

And another called `Transportes`, this is for relation (and only have 2 columns that are the data I need of each other)

That's my code:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Transporte]
(
    [MaquinistaId] INT NOT NULL,
    [TractoristaId] INT NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [FK_Transporte_Maquinista] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([MaquinistaId]) REFERENCES [Maquinista]([MaquinistaId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Transporte_Tractorista] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([TractoristaId]) REFERENCES [Tractorista]([TractoristaId])
)
```

The error:

> The referenced table [dbo].[Transporte] contains no primary or candidate keys that match the referencing column list in the foreign key.

Comment: The error seems really clear to me.  What don't you understand about it?

Comment: tryadding: PRIMARY KEY ([MaquinistaId], [TractoristaId])

Comment: Maquinista.MaquinistaId should be either a primary key or have a unique constraint defined on it (hence: candidate key), in case you have doubts about the message.

Comment: Or instead of your two constraints, try using:  CONSTRAINT PK_Transporte_Group PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([MaquinistaId], [TractoristaId])